# Default Shell theme overridden in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I have recently switched to ubuntu 22.04 and I installed the BigSur GTK shell theme. But after installing this theme, when I change my shell theme to default, it always uses this Bigsurr theme and not other themes. Even other themes are not working properly. I cannot even take screenshots now. I try resetting my gnome setting but it didn't work. I also tried uninstallng the whiteSurr Theme but that also didn't work.

Have anyone faced this issue before. please help.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you changed anything inside `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`, you can try to restore its contents following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/636819/500206).

It's also may be an 'User Themes' extension problem, which doesn't work well in Ubuntu 22.04, try to uninstall it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230635)